# How do I launch a .exe file with a button click from a menu inside a Zinc 4.0 built flash project

Tags: flash, actionscript, fscommand

I am current working on a project to place a Zinc 4.0 built flash menu on a CD. One of the buttons on the menu needs to open a external catalog that is a .exe file. I was able to use the fscommand scripts to get this to work in a flash projector.  But I wanted some more options in the design of the windows itself so I ran it through Zinc 4.0 instead.  Now the file no longer executes on the button click.

I tried some of the some Zinc 4.0 scripting and it still does not work.

This is the code snippet I am currently using.

```
view_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openCat);
function openCat (e:MouseEvent):void {
fscommand("exec",mdm.Application.path+"cellrun.exe");
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: I solved it and so hopefully no one has to go through my stress here is my working code.

Comment: view_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,viewCat);

function viewCat(e:MouseEvent){
 var app:String = "cellrun.app";
if(mdm.Application && mdm.Application.path.length > 0)
{
 // system dependant separator is needed to compute
 // subdirectory path to "fscommand" dir where exe is stored
 var separator:String = mdm.Application.path.substr(-1);
 // path (absolute) to "fscommand" location
 app = mdm.Application.path+"fscommand"+separator+app;
 // now execute it via {mdm} script
 mdm.System.exec(app);
} else
{
 // execute with fscommand
 flash.system.fscommand("exec", app);
}

}